# update table with info from another table of same name an fields

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to update a table with info from another table on the same db with same table name.
I just want the info to be the same , no primary key or constraint involve just a straight replacement of records and I keep getting errors. below is

**my query:**

```
UPDATE VNDLOC
 SET
 VNDLOC=VNDLOC
 FROM rockpot
```

**Edit:**

```
UPDATE VNDLOW 
    SET EOBTYP = VNDLOW.EOBTYP, 
    EDI_X12_835_VERSION = VNDLOW.EDI_X12_835_VERSION 
    FROM ROCKPOT
```

Comment: your question is not clear,,, please improve your question

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Matching column on both sides then something like below will work for you:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Column1 =  Table2.ColumnX,  Column2 =  Table2.ColumnY
FROM Table2 
WHERE Table1.MatchingColumn = Table2.MatchingColumn
```

Comment: this is my modification but it's not recognizing the db name UPDATE VNDLOW
 SET EOBTYP =  VNDLOW.EOBTYP,  EDI_X12_835_VERSION =  VNDLOW.EDI_X12_835_VERSION 
FROM ROCKPOT